# Subscriber throws "can not read property subscribers of undefined" in NestJS / TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have a NestJS app which I wanted to use a TypeORM subscriber but unfortunately, whenever the app starts, I get an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribers' of undefined

So it seems like the connection is undefined, although I set up the TypeORM Module as per documentation.

```js
imports: [
  ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
  TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    type: 'postgres',
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
    entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    subscribers: ['dist/**/*.subscriber{.ts,.js}'],
    synchronize: true, // This for development
    autoLoadEntities: true,
  }),
],
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution to your problem  ?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and it turns out I was missing the decorator `@Injectable()` on the subscriber class:

```
@Injectable()
export default class EventTemplateRelationSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<EventTemplateRelation> {
    ...
}
```